# How does the rake() from survey package calculates the weights?

Tags: survey, survey-weights

I run rake function from the survey package of R in my data and got the weights by calling the weights() function. Sample code

```
small.svy.unweighted <- svydesign(ids=~1, strata = ~HZIP ,data=HHdata, weights=~Weights_1)

small.svy.rake <- rake(design = small.svy.unweighted, 
                   sample.margins = list(~agecats, ~zip),
                   population.margins = list(age.dist, zip.dist))
```

Questions:

1. Are the weights return by weights(small.svy.rake) function become the new samplings weights? That is, if i run the analysis in the eg. SPSS, the weights will be my input weights?
2. How does the algorithm manually computes the weights? I tried to manually compute it but I could not get the same weights return by weights().

Comment: What is `survey` package, what language? Language specific questions can be off-topic.

Comment: Rim or raking weighting is a way to compute frequency weights for 2+ categorical features, i.e. for multiway frequency table. It is based on _proportional fitting algorithm_ which is quite simple. Iteratively bring marginal profiles to the wanted (target) ones by multiplying by coefficient `target freqs / currently observed freqs`. The method is called "rim" because it goes though marginals (sides) of the table on each iteration.

Comment: (cont.) Rim weighting assumes that "disproportions" in the cells of the input table were due to affected main effects only, and it aims to recover the situation "going same way back". In SPSS, you can use advanced (with options) rim-weighting macro found on my web-page (package called "weighting groups"). There is also an extension command Rake written by Jon Peck and included right with SPSS.

Comment: @ttnphns: sorry, this is for the survey package in R language

Comment: @ttnphns: I added this question in stackoverflow just in case this is off topic in statsexchange.

Comment: Did you read the help file...? It says it operates by repeated calls to `postStratify()`; if you look there there is an associated paper (Valliant R (1993) Post-stratification and conditional variance estimation. JASA 88: 89-96) that could quell some of your confusion.

Comment: thanks for your inputs ttnhns and gammer. I will read the infos provided.

Comment: You are not suppose to crosspost.  Pick one site and delete the question on the other(s).

Comment: hi, if you don't find the answer you are looking for in the documentation, you will need to either view the code by typing `survey:::rake` or step through the function with `debug(rake)`.  you can also type `debug(weights)` to view what happens inside of that function

Comment: @AnthonyDamico Thanks for this info. This helps a lot.

Comment: @MichaelChernick sorry I did not know. But I already remove it last night as it is off topic in SO.

Comment: @dixi See what you can do to edit your question to get it reopened.  We need to understand the statistical question if there is one to be made.